# Raspbian Lite not playing vlc audio through HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, headless, raspbian-lite, vlc

I have an RPi 3 running Raspbian Lite with vlc installed, I'm trying to get this setup for a TV, to play some branding from a directory on loop. Currently there's an issue with playing the audio from the MP4 clip through an HDMI cable. Sound plays through the auxiliary jack, but not on the TV. I've tried the following

- Uncommenting **hdmi_group=1**,**hdmi_drive=2**, and **dtparam=audio=on** in /boot/config.txt
- Using **hdmi_drive=4** and **hdmi_drive=1**
- Ensuring that **snd_bcm2835** is loaded on boot
- Ensuring that the playback device is set to HDMI and not headphones
- Uninstalling and reinstalling PulseAudio

I've also been attempting speaker-test to verify that vlc is not the issue here. OMXPlayer is not installed

Edit: Turns out the specific TV was telling the Pi that it was DMT instead of CEA. Its a weird tv/monitor that I used for testing, so I tried it on another TV and it seems to have solved my issue. No configuration necessary.

Comment: how do you install vlc in Raspberry Pi OS lite? Doesn't installing vlc mean that all the X11 GUI stuff needs to be installed?

Comment: what does hdmi_drive=4 do? why would you even try hdmi_drive=1 if you want sound coming from HDMI since that option would turn sound off, by its very definition?

Comment: have you tried removing `dtparam=audio=on` (or commenting it out) ... since you DON'T want onboard audio?